# How use Qualify row_number in teradata

Tags: teradata, rank, row-number

how are you?

I never used qualify row_number()/rank() and I have some questions.

I am trying this query in teradata:

```
select sit_site_id
     , count(distinct shp_shipment_id) 
from WHOWNER.BT_SHP_SHIPMENTS
group by sit_site_id
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sit_site_id 
                     ORDER BY count(distinct shp_shipment_id) ) = 3
```

But the result is: 'No data available in table'.

I want to get the first 3 sit_site_id values with more shp_shipment_id.

Where is my error?

Thanks!

Comment: The GROUP BY returns a single row per site_id and then you try to get the 3rd row, of course that returns no rows. You probably want something like `QUALIFY RANK() OVER ( 
                     ORDER BY count(distinct shp_shipment_id) ) <= 3` which returns the three highest counts.

Comment: Do you need top 3 `site_id` per every `shipment_id`? Kindly share sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the first 3 sit_site_id values with more shp_shipment_id

If so, then you do not need to use RANK() / ROW_NUMBER(). Instead, you can just use TOP. Your query should be like below:

```
select TOP 3 sit_site_id
     , count(distinct shp_shipment_id) shp_shipment_id_cnt
from WHOWNER.BT_SHP_SHIPMENTS
group by sit_site_id
order by shp_shipment_id_cnt DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `qualify` for this, then you can do:

```
select sit_site_id, count(distinct shp_shipment_id) 
from WHOWNER.BT_SHP_SHIPMENTS
group by sit_site_id
qualify row_number() over (order by count(distinct shp_shipment_id) desc) <= 3;
```

However, I would recommend `top` as in @Clark's answer.

Comment: Why do you prefer TOP over QUALIFY?

Comment: @dnoeth . . . (1)  I don't see a need to calculate the row number separately from the `order by`.  Do they have the same execution plan? (2) I *really* prefer `fetch first`, because that is the ANSI standard.

Comment: There's some generic optimization for *top-n-rows* and thus it's the same plan for both variations. I usually don't recommend TOP because the syntax allows only a subset of ranking functionality (and whenever I read TOP I must skip to the end of the query to see if there's an ORDER BY).